# Android Thread loop to check httppost

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a problem on refresh the listview using thread. How to use it ?

But the current problem i been using this method

private String getServerDatas(String returnString) {

```
   InputStream is = null;
   String result = "";
  List<Order> listOfPhonebook = new ArrayList<Order>();



    try{

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(returnString);
        //  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
         Toast.makeText(Chef.this, e.toString()+"Number 1 " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

         try{

             JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);


           totalorder = jArray.length();

           array_list=new String[totalorder];
            table_list= new String[totalorder];

             for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);



            array_list[i] =  " Table "+json_data.getString("table_id")+" : "+json_data.getString("order_foodname")+" x "+json_data.getString("order_quantity");
            table_list[i]=json_data.getString("table_id");


            listOfPhonebook.add(new Order("Table :"+json_data.getString("table_id"),json_data.getString("order_foodname"),json_data.getString("order_quantity")));
           // Toast.makeText(Chef.this, table_list[i] , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }

        adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, listOfPhonebook);


            adapters = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,
                     R.layout.row, R.id.label, array_list);


      //       LayoutAnimationController controller 
      //       = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(
       //        this, R.layout.list_layout_controller);
       //     lv1.setLayoutAnimation(controller);


    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }


    return returnString; 
}
```

i use json to get the file i added the string into adapter

Comment: what is the exact problem? do you get an error message?

Comment: erm.. i wanna to call this  String getServerDatas(String returnString)  in a thread .. an endless loop .. that update the adapter.. while update the listview.

Comment: in forum shows that i couldnt call an endless thread loop in a ui.. so how can i update the adapter and show in the listview in real time??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bordering on mind reading, but it sounds like you're trying to refresh the ListView outside of the UI-Thread. You cannot do that. Wrap the `notifyDataSetChanged`-Call inside a `Runnable` and post it to the UI-Thread, using a `Handler`:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

...

mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
});
```

Comment: I still cant get it... cause i been using the private String getServerDatas(String returnString) to get the url input and start getting the value from mysql.. but i couldnt get the connection work in thread.. i need it to be endless loop thread.. which any new data added will be add inside adapter and show in the listview