# Android endless loop to check for incoming data using httppost

Tags: android, multithreading, http-post

Currently I'm having problem when I try to refresh or update the listview adapter via HttpPost.

I want to make an endless thread calling the HttpPost connection in order to fetch the data and store inside an adapter. At the end I want to re-set the adapter to the listview. I could make it work on button. But I want work with the thread that keep loop to the data in mysql.

Please help me. I cant find any solution.

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    lv2=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView02);

    tvalert=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewalert);

    getServerDatas("http://172.50.2.66/ChefGetOrdered.php");

  tv = new TextView(this);
   tv.setText("Incoming Order");

    tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText(" Waiting list");

    lv1.addHeaderView(tv);
    lv2.addHeaderView(tv1);
    lv2.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv2.setClickable(true); 
    lv2.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv1.setClickable(true);
    lv1.setDivider(null);
    lv1.setDividerHeight(0);
    lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

        Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
        int a = (int) lv1.getItemIdAtPosition(position);
        int ab = a+1;

        Toast.makeText(Chef.this, o.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(Chef.this, ab+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


      }
    });
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCheck);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);



     }






        private String getServerDatas(String returnString) {

        InputStream is = null;
   String result = "";
  List<Order> listOfPhonebook = new ArrayList<Order>();



    try{

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(returnString);

           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
         Toast.makeText(Chef.this, e.toString()+"Number 1 " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

         try{

             JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);


           totalorder = jArray.length();

           array_list=new String[totalorder];
            table_list= new String[totalorder];




             for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);





            table_list[i]=json_data.getString("table_id");


            listOfPhonebook.add(new Order("Table :"+json_data.getString("table_id")+"\n Time:",json_data.getString("order_foodname"),json_data.getString("order_quantity")));

             }

        adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, listOfPhonebook);





    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }


    return returnString; 
}
```

Comment: Please, be more specific. You have succeeded doing it with http post and now you want ot do the same with db? Or you haven't and ask to help with updating the view after getting data over http?

Comment: i was  able to get the data and set it to listview via adapter.. but i couldnt do it in a thread a endless loop thread . The loop will keep track if any change in mysql database.

Comment: What is exact problems? Exceptions? Troubles? Anything else?

Comment: if i put a thread in oncreate .. force close.
well i was put a public void run() {  while (true) {

Comment: post your code and exception please.

Comment: i already add the code.. but i didnt put any thread.. cause i tried it in alot different way but doesnt seem could be work lead to force close..

Comment: problem is where should i put the thread? and how the handler use? . Sorry sir im  noob in android and thanks for ur help

Comment: How does this question differ from you previous one? voting for close.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Thread loop to check httppost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408341/android-thread-loop-to-check-httppost)

Comment: erm.. i thought i was asking the wrong question in first that why i create a new question

Comment: so we continue this thread in this or the Android Thread loop to check httppost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstracting of loop and getting the data, the necessary thing you should have to update UI from other thread is a Handler. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Comment: actually im not really understand how to use the handler either. if sir could give me some example how to do it that would be great.